Is it safe to store an AES-encrypted password in a Secure, httpOnly cookie?
I need to connect my webapp (NodeJs backend) to an external system that authenticates users with login and password. Every page of the webapp will interact with this system and will need to initiate a connection first. Obviously I don't want my users to enter their credentials on every page...
Ideally I don't want to temporarily store passwords on the server because it would require to create a scheduled job that removes expired "sessions".
My idea would be to do the following:

When a user arrives on the webapp, we generate an IV that is written in a Secure, httpOnly cookie
After successful login, we encrypt the provided password when a secret key and the IV from the cookie
The encrypted password is then written in a Secure, httpOnly cookie
On every other page, we read the encrypted password from the cookie and decrypt it server side to log the user in

Is it safe enough if I restrict the cookies to a specific path and SameSite: Strict ?
Thanks
